# How do I find which object is EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject detecting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject in a script and Unity returns True even though I would swear there is no UI/EventSystem object beneath the pointer.

How can I find information about the object the EventSystem is detecting?

Comment: I don't believe you even if you **swear**. Show me some proof

Comment: JK ! check my answer, hope it will help

Comment: I've come across the same thing today. The problem is that panels,... trigger `IsPointerOverGameObject()` too (the Canvas does not - luckily), so if you want to know if the mouse cursor is hovering over a button that's also the child of a bigger e.g. panel `IsPointerOverGameObject()` won't work because it doesn't tell you what kind of GameObject the pointer is over. I'm now using Programmer's suggestion (IPointerEnterHandler) and attached the script to the parent panel. Btw, `currentSelectedGameObject` only triggers when you click on a button (mouse over isn't enough!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've stumbled upon this thread and wasn't quite happy with the solution provided, so here's another implementation to share:

```
public class StandaloneInputModuleV2 : StandaloneInputModule
{
    public GameObject GameObjectUnderPointer(int pointerId)
    {
        var lastPointer = GetLastPointerEventData(pointerId);
        if (lastPointer != null)
            return lastPointer.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject;
        return null;
    }

    public GameObject GameObjectUnderPointer()
    {
        return GameObjectUnderPointer(PointerInputModule.kMouseLeftId);
    }
}
```

Looking at the EventSystem's editor output showing names for the GameObjects, I decided that some functionality was already there and there should be means of using it. After diving into the [opened source](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/6a975b5d7ec7/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/?at=2017.1) of the forementioned `EventSystem` and `IsPointerOverGameObject` (overrided in `PointerInputModule`), I thought it'll be easier to extend the default `StandaloneInputModule`.

Usage is simple, just replace the default one added on the scene with the EventSystem and reference in code like:

```
private static StandaloneInputModuleV2 currentInput;
private StandaloneInputModuleV2 CurrentInput
{
    get
    {
        if (currentInput == null)
        {
            currentInput = EventSystem.current.currentInputModule as StandaloneInputModuleV2;
            if (currentInput == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Missing StandaloneInputModuleV2.");
                // some error handling
            }
        }

        return currentInput;
    }
}
```

...

```
var currentGO = CurrentInput.GameObjectUnderPointer();
```

Comment: 2021 update: looks like the new Input System (1.0.1) doesn't really support this quite elegant solution - the structs are fairly similar, but the data is made private so you basically need to alter the original logic in order to make it work.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.UI.InputSystemUIInputModule.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_UI_InputSystemUIInputModule_IsPointerOverGameObject_System_Int32_

Answer (score 16):

In your `update()` :

```
 if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
 {
     PointerEventData pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
     pointer.position = Input.mousePosition;

     List<RaycastResult> raycastResults = new List<RaycastResult>();
     EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResults);

     if(raycastResults.Count > 0)
     {
         foreach(var go in raycastResults)
         {  
             Debug.Log(go.gameObject.name,go.gameObject);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was able to find the UI element and then add a parent to its GameObject with a CanvasGroup component with options set to ignore mouse clicks

Answer (score 1):

You can find out more info about which GameObject `EventSystem` is detecting by implementing `IPointerClickHandler` and overriding the `OnPointerEnter` function.

If this is a UI component such as Image/RawImage and others, you want to detect, this should do it:

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class MouseEnterScript: MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Name: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

If this is a Mesh with a Collider(3D) such as **Box Collider**, Add `PhysicsRaycaster` to the Camera then use the first code in this answer to detect which GameObject the mouse is over.

```
void Start()
{
    Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<PhysicsRaycaster>();
}
```

If this is a `SpriteRenderer` with a 2D Collider such as **Box Collider 2D**, Add `Physics2DRaycaster` to the Camera then use the first code in this answer to detect which GameObject the mouse is over

```
void Start()
{
    Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<Physics2DRaycaster>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion above i used it this way

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Is the pointer hovering over a game object with the given name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Name of the game object hovering over</param>
    /// <returns>Status</returns>
    private bool IsPointerOverGameObjectName(string name)
    {
        PointerEventData pointer = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        pointer.position = Input.mousePosition;

        List<RaycastResult> raycastResults = new List<RaycastResult>();
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointer, raycastResults);

        if (raycastResults.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var go in raycastResults)
            {
                if (go.gameObject.name == name)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```